# Twilio <Gather> perform webhook action too slow

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-twiml

I'm writing an IVR application using Twilio in python
here is sample Twiml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather action="/twilio/ivr/action/callback" input="dtmf" method="GET">
        <Say>Press 1 to do something</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

Sample Twiml in `twilio/ivr/action/callback`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Sa>Please say something</Say>
    <Record method="GET" timeout="3" trim="do-not-trim" />
</Response>
```

But when user press 1, I have to wait 5 to 6 seconds to receive callback action. I think is too slow for my IVR system. Is this the normal reaction time? Or is this related to my country?

My service region is Taiwan, and server built on AWS Tokyo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `timeout` attribute on `<Gather>`, so it will not default to 5 seconds. Also if you expect only one digit, you can use the `numDigits` attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather 
      action="/twilio/ivr/action/callback" 
      input="dtmf" 
      method="GET" 
      timeout="3" 
      numDigits="1"
    >
        <Say>Press 1 to do something</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

More here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes